# how to make the input not read a certain number

Tags: java, max, counter

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number (0 to quit): ");
        //largest to-do
        double largest = scan.nextDouble();
        double count = 0;

        while (largest != 0) {
            double input = scan.nextDouble();
            //max
            if (input > largest) {
                // not zero
                // while (input > largest){
                //
                // }

                largest = input;
                //counter
                count = 0;

            }
            //counter start
            if(input==largest){
                count++;
            }
            if (input == 0) {
                System.out.println("Largest #: " + largest);
                System.out.println("Occurance: " + count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program works! however, its not that complete I think...
Like if a user tries to enter

```
-17 -5 -2 -1 -1 -1 0
```

it outputs:

```
Max: 0
Occurrence: 1
```

Though: in my mind I want it to be:

```
Max: -1
Occurrence: 3
```

how would I do this WITHOUT using arrays? I know its in that part of the code I started above the counter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So 0 is meant to be the stopping point? Why not make a letter or some other character be the stopping point?

Comment: If you want to keep the zero number as exit, you'll need an additional check at `input > largest` exactly like you commented: `input != 0 && input > largest` because 0 is read and is processed as well

Comment: @dimwittedanimal I could try to do that, though I just wanted to see how you can omit a number in this process

Comment: @hellothere I would do what Al1 suggested then.

Comment: @Al1 O! I see ok, thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number (0 to quit): ");

        double largest = 0, nextDouble;
        int count = 0;

        while ((nextDouble = scan.nextDouble()) != 0) {
            if (nextDouble > largest || largest == 0) {
                largest = nextDouble;
                count = 1;
            }
            else if (nextDouble == largest) count++;
        }

        scan.close();

        if (count == 0) {
            System.out.println("No number entered!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Largest #: " + largest);
        System.out.println("Occurance: " + count);

    }
}
```

Comment: dang OK , I was trying to figure out why if you (for my program) entered the highest negative number multiple times-- it counts it 1 less.